# jquery addClass to related element issue

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have the following code. When someone clicks on one of the 'a.mainSubMenuLinkA' it triggers a page change successfully. After this I need to add the class 'active' to the previous 'a.mainSubMenuHeadingLinkA'.

```
<li><a class="mainSubMenuHeadingLinkA">Approvals</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a id="photos_profile" class="mainSubMenuLinkA">Profile Photos</a></li>
        <li><a id="photos_gallery" class="mainSubMenuLinkA">Gallery Photos</a></li>
        <li><a id="text_review" class="mainSubMenuLinkA">Text Review</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li><a class="mainSubMenuHeadingLinkA">Information</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="index.htm#">Information 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.htm#">Information 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.htm#">Information 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

There are several chunks of code like this (eg: multiple mainSubMenuHeadingLinkA classes) so I need to find the one that is previous to anchor clicked.

I have tried many combination of jquery to .addClass() eg:

```
$(this).closest('li .mainSubMenuHeadingLinkA').addClass('active');
$(this).closest('.mainSubMenuHeadingLinkA').addClass('active');
```

Note: $(this) relates to 'a.mainSubMenuLinkA' as I can add a class directly to this email... just not to the 'a.mainSubMenuHeadingLinkA'.

Any advice?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(this).closest('li').prev('li').find('.mainSubMenuHeadingLinkA').addClass('active');
```

Comment: $(this).closest('li').parents('li').find('.mainSubMenuHeadingLinkA').addClass('active'); - this worked... cheers